# WPF ActualWidth and ActualHeight not scaled with ScaleTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, scaletransform

I am using WPF .NET 4.5.1.  I have several Borders added to a canvas.  In the code behind, I apply a RenderTransform to scale all of them by a certain amount:

```
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in OverlayCanvas.Children)
            {
                child.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(XScale, YScale, 0, child.Height/2);
            }
```

Elsewhere, I try to use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the Borders, but they aren't scaled by the XScale and YScale values.  I have also tried using a LayoutTransform, but that didn't work either.

Do I need to resign myself to having to apply the scale to the ActualHeight and ActualWidth whenever I want to use them?  Or is there an easier way?

UPDATE:

I did find one way using an extension method for FrameworkElement:  GetBounds().

I'm not sure when it was added to the .NET framework, but it sure was helpful in this situation.  It gave me the exact height and width along with where my controls were located relative to other controls as calculated after the transform.

I would still love to hear a better way to do this if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: This seems to be a WPF feature: [link](http://tinyurl.com/otvpk5s). So it looks like you'll indeed have to calculate it yourself.